# Dev tools pixel width and body element now same

Tags: css, media-queries, google-chrome-devtools

I have a very strange situation where the current pixel width shown on chrome dev tools is different to what's displayed when I right click on the body element and see the full width of the body element.

For example I am using

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .card {
        max-width: 356px;

    }
}
```

However what I find is that this style is applied when the pixel width is 1240px (as shown on dev tools).....however the body element is 992px. What could be the cause of this?

I've put this metatag on my header in the html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

edit: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQXGgg

Break seems to work on codepen browser but not when I run it locally :s

Comment: Please share html and css or link of your page?

Comment: Maybe you've zoomed the entire page via Ctrl-wheel etc. because 1240/992 = exactly 125%. Reset the zoom level.

Comment: @wOxxOm genius! please write answer and i'll accept